# Pandas cumsum with keys

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have two DataFrames (first, second):

| index_first | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 200 | 2 |
| 2 | 300 | 3 |

| index_second | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 50 | 10 |
| 1 | 100 | 20 |
| 2 | 150 | 30 |

Next I concat the two DataFrames with keys:

```
z = pd.concat([first, second],keys=['x','y'])
```

My goal is to calculate the cumulative sum of `value_1` and `value_2` in z considering the keys.
So the final DataFrame should look like this:

| index_z | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x,0 | 100 | 1 |
| x,1 | 300 | 3 |
| x,2 | 600 | 6 |
| y,0 | 50 | 10 |
| y,1 | 150 | 30 |
| y,2 | 300 | 60 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) by first level created by `key`s from `concat`:

```
df = z.groupby(level=0).cumsum()
print (df)
               value_1  value_2
  index_first                  
x 0                100        1
  1                300        3
  2                600        6
y 0                 50       10
  1                150       30
  2                300       60
```